# passing parameter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the next report…
[image]

I wanted to add a parameter… Which would be user entered…  The thing is that, if the parameter is empty, I want it not to filter anything… and if populated, to filter by that…

Can this be achieved? I reckon that if empty will do

```
WHERE PARAMETER = ‘’
```

and of course that’s not the intended behavior…

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dummy value in your selection list.

For example:

```
select
'All' as [Label],
null as [Value]

union all

select
    a.Name as [Label],
    a.Value as [Value]
from dbo.HereAreMyValues as [a]
```

This will give you a selection option of "All" to show all (i.e. no filtering) in your parameter.

You can then reference this as..

```
from dbo.Data as [d]
where (d.Value = (@Parameter) or (@Parameter) is null)
```

This will give you the data that either matches the parameter value, or all if the parameter value is null.

Comment: This would only work if the parameter has the "null" checkbox, right? If the person leaves it blank, it would return nothing...

Comment: Correct. In my report where I use this option, I have a parameter that filters this list. So my first parameter you select Staff Type, which then gives you a list of Staff to pick from (or "All" as the null value). This allows me to only have a single staff member or all staff selected - nothing in between. The cascading parameter means that the null checkbox disappears (which makes it look nicer).